# Can't print text file using Java 8 in Windows 7

Tags: java, printing, javafx, java-8

I've created a report and exported it as a text file, to print in a matrix printer, however, the result of the job is a blank page. I did the same in ubuntu and it is printing correctly.
Is it a Java bug?

This is a example code I did to show you the problem:

```
public class PrintError extends Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws PrintException {
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        printerJob.showPrintDialog(stage);
        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(printerJob.getJobSettings().getCopies()));
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new JobName("test", Locale.getDefault()));
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc mydoc = new SimpleDoc(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/should-be-printed.txt"), flavor, null);
        DocPrintJob job = getPrintService(printerJob.getPrinter().getName()).createPrintJob();
        job.print(mydoc, printRequestAttributeSet);
    }

    private PrintService getPrintService(String name) {
        for (PrintService printService : java.awt.print.PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices()) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(printService.getName())) {
                return printService;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This example was created in JavaFx 8 and is running in Java build 1.8.0-b132 in Windows 7.
I've also created a simple project at [github](https://github.com/brevleq/print-error)

Comment: Which PDF Printers are you trying to use?    Also, can you please post an example of the text report that is generated and also what gets created by Ubuntu?

Comment: JavaFX has a [printing framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/package-summary.html).  As your application was created in JavaFX, I think you should try using that framework.

Comment: The examples that shows how use the printing framework only shows how to print the content of the application (Nodes). This framework could print a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.html#skip.navbar.top):

> #### Recommended DocFlavors
>
> The Java Print Service API does not define any mandatorily supported DocFlavors. …

When you have a `PrintService` instance, you can use the method `getSupportedDocFlavors()` to find out which flavors it supports.

When you find out that none of the `DocFlavor. INPUT_STREAM. TEXT_PLAIN_…` flavors is in the list, it doesn’t help to use `AUTOSENSE` as that simply means “best guess” and it’s unlikely that a `PrintService` will guess a type it doesn’t support, instead, it’s more likely that the data will be misinterpreted as one of the formats it supports.

On my Windows machine, none of the provided `PrintService`s supports printing plaintext…

Comment: I didn't noticed that windows's pdf printers can't print text file directly.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across a similar problem (Printing blank in Windows 7 but working in Windows 10 in my case), but the DocFlavor is set correctly (i.e. One supported by a chosen print service)...

I was able to solve my issue by updating the JRE from 32-bit 8u101 to 64-bit 8u121.